# Skyrim settings not saving. Forced into windows mode at 800x600

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I installed skyrim via steam and I adjusted the settings to be full screen and my native 1600x1200 resolution, and started the game, and it started in windowed mode 800x600.
I tried many times, and even tried restarting my computer.

I then tried to at least change bFullScreen to 1 in the settings file in the Skyrim folder.
This didn't work, leading me to believe the file is out-right being ignored.

Anyone else that has had this problem and has found a solution?

More specs:
gtx 470, uac is on low, compatibility options aren't explicitly turned on, it is being run as admin. fully updated Windows 7 is the OS. It is also very fresh install... I reformatted just yesterday.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE! What operating system are you running? Have you tried installing new drivers? Have you tried running it as an administrator? Do you have UAC disabled which you really shouldn't? Do you have any compatibility options enabled in the properties?

Comment: added more information under "More specs"

Comment: There are 3 setting files: Skyrim.ini and SkyrimPrefs.ini located in \Users\[your username]\Documents\My Games\Skyrim, and SkyrimPrefs.ini in \Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\skyrim\Skyrim.
I haven't done much testing with it, but it seems the latter one is overridden by the first two.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll look at the documents settings tonight.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the location you mentioned does not exist...

Before I installed Skyrim my "documents" library was moved to a different already existing folder.

Comment: I tried verifying the game cache. It said it found a problem, so I can it again, and the second time it said it was fine, but my issue still exists.

I guess I'll just reinstall =(

Comment: Tried reinstalling. Didn't help.

Comment: That could be a problem. Have you tried creating the location yourself? Also, add @Arkive in any replies so I get notified.

Comment: @Arkive I created the My Games\Skyrim directory in my personal user folder and copied the SkyrimPrefs.ini from the game directory to that location. I also copied it and renamed it to Skyrim.ini, because the game folder doesn't have a Skyrim.ini file.

It still doesn't work. Next, I'll try reinstalling the game with those directories existing.

Answer (score 3):

I simply disabled UAC and that solved my problem. [I also turned off windows firewall, but I think it was the UAC that was stopping things]

I hope if anyone else has this issue, that disabling UAC and their firewall solves the problem.